# Is the maximum norm on a vector space complete?

Tags: vector-spaces, complete-spaces

K is a complete non-archimedean field, and then K[x] can be seen as a vector space on K with infinite dimension. For f(x) in K[x], its norm is the maximum valuation the coefficients. Is this norm complete, that is to say, any Cauchy series is convergent.

Comment: Let $u \in K$ have a norm between $0$ and $1$ (strictly), and consider the series $\sum_{n \geq 0}{u^nx^n}$.

Comment: The completion of $C_{00}$ is $C_0$ under any complete field when using the sup norm.